# Should I list on my CV research assistantship positions under grants&awards?

Tags: cv, research-assistantship, awards, funding

Background of person is: first year Phd student, no publications, no research grants, but I have received a fellowship for my first semester that paid my stipend and tuition, so should I list the total amount with stipend and tuition?

Also during my MS I was hired as an RA and received stipend+tuition? Can I list that as a total amount per year, or total amount for the two years, or should I separate the different amounts (tuition/stipend). Isn't this a fellowship/scholarship/grant of some sort since rarely do master students get this kind of RAship?

edit: while RA's are common in the US and the fact that they pay stipend/tuition is well known, in other countries people might think that if I list it only as a job they might not realize it also paid my tuition, which for foreign students in the US can be quite high. I want to convey the importance of this achievement and monetary importance to a crowd outside the USA.

Comment: No. Standard assistantships are not "awards." (If it's a "merit award" assistantship of some kind, that's a different matter!)

Comment: list your fellowships under honors and awards and your research assistantship under work/job experience or positions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although merit is certainly a factor in the hiring of research assistants,   most people don't consider assistantships as "grants or awards". They are jobs. List them under "Positions Held" or "Academic Appointments" or the equivalent heading on your CV. Do not list your salary or the amount of your stipend - that's not anybody's business except you and your department.

Some fellowships might be considered awards. They would usually be explicitly competitive in nature, and given by outside agencies. "Named" fellowships from endowed funds might also count, even if awarded by your department. But a research assistantship is not a fellowship.

Comment: I understand the argument about the stipend, but a regular job doesn't pay your $20,000 tuition bill, and considering RA's are competitive I want to list this somewhere.

Comment: @user4050: Regular jobs don't, but research assistantships pretty much always do. Academics know this, and you can be confident that for academic purposes, someone who sees it under "Positions" will understand that it says something about your accomplishments. (For industry, the situation may be different, and in that case Workplace.se may be a better place to ask.)

Answer (score 3):

> should I list the total amount with stipend and tuition?

No, don't list this because it's irrelevant and sooner or later you'll remove it as your CV grows. You can just add it in the `Honors and Awards` section of your CV, but don't put numbers.

> Also during my MS I was hired as an RA and received stipend+tuition? Can I list that as a total amount per year, or total amount for the two years, or should I separate the different amounts (tuition/stipend).

Same as before.

> Isn't this a fellowship/scholarship/grant of some sort since rarely do master students get this kind of RAship?

In this case I would just put it under `Research Experience`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, one can include anything in a CV *as long as the "target" of the CV would be interested in it*. This raises the question why exactly you are now compiling a CV in the first place.

**Are you looking to change programs? Apply for a grant? Just wanting to show off on your web page?**

Whatever the answer to this is, ask yourself the question whether whoever is supposed to read the CV would really care about your funding sources. In most cases, I would assume that the answer to this is *no*, unless the funding sources are particularly competitive and known outside your university.

Finally:

> Isn't this a fellowship/scholarship/grant of some sort since rarely do master students get this kind of RAship?

Nope. If it's a RAship it's a RAship. That you got it earlier than others does not "upgrade" the prize in any way. Generally, resist the temptation to upsell your various prizes / grants / fellowships.

Comment: One should probably compile one's CV continuously so that one doesn't forget to put stuff on it. I wish I'd gotten in the habit when I was a student.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with the other answers. At least in fields where a substantial number of students self fund their PhD, having any funding is a big deal. I think you should put the fellowships and their amounts, under "grants and awards", although it might be reasonable to change the title to something like "funding" or "fellowships, grants, and awards".

While a departmental fellowship (or funding from someone else's grant) is not particularly prestigious, it is important. For example, a student with guaranteed money from his/her department or advisor has little incentive to apply for external money (and in many cases might even be ineligible). In evaluating students as potential post docs, I look at students who have had to self fund their studies very differently from those who have had funding. That said, it is important that you do not make too much of a departmental fellowship as it is generally the least prestigious type of funding you can get.

Comment: *I look at students who have had to self fund their studies very differently from those who have had funding.* - [Interesting](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/8036/11365), do you usually even know, given that many (most?) people *don't* put departmental fellowships in their CV?

Comment: @ff524 If I don't see any source of external funding on a CV, I ask potential post docs if they applied for any funding. If they haven't, I ask why and the answer is often "I already had funding".

Comment: I was not referring to a fellowship but to a research assistantship, in this case a professor received a grant and then hired someone as an RA. I agree that fellowships should go under grants/awards.

Comment: @user4050 the first sentence of your question says "fellowship". It doesn't matter what it is called, it is the funding that matters.

Comment: @StrongBad sorry you are right, I am asking two separate questions.

Comment: @StrongBad *I look at students who have had to self fund their studies very differently [...]* How do you evaluate self-funding researchers' profile?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I get very excited about potential post docs who have gone out and secured their own funding in the past. I get a lot less excited about potential post docs who have needed funding and either are unable to get it or have not tried.

Comment: @StrongBad I always think that professors are pessimistic about self-funding scholars; because it may come to mind that because these people have money, they can hide their low research potential and ease their way to an academic position.